# Debian dmesg thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed

Tags: debian, power-management, dmesg

I'm using Debian 9(stretch) with kernel Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 on a Thinkpad T440p. I keep receiving logs by the second from dmesg about one particular issue I seem to not find a solution to on the Web. From startup, dmesg continues to log this particular message which is accompanied with a steady 3-time power LED blink

```
[time] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
```

This has become so rampant that my laptop's battery life is degrading too quickly (it's an original and not a replacement). I use tlp and disabling it does not seem to solve the issue.

Any help to quickly address this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing the power adapter, the logs and intermittent blinking of the power LED has ceased. That definitely meant that the power adapter was faulty.